# Mysql warning: InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace `foo`.`bar` because the DISCARD flag is set

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.7

Whenever my MySQL 5.7 starts I get the warning

```
InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace `foo`.`bar` because the DISCARD flag is set
```

bar is a table I experimented with long time ago with `import tablespace`, but its long deleted and I don't see any files associated with it in the database directory.

`drop table bar` doesn't work.

How do I get ride of this warning ?

Answer (score 2):

## **Why this warning pops up:**

You discarded the tablespace and physically removed the .frm file from the data directory. But still, tablespace information is present in the InnoDB data dictionary table. (you can check *innodb_sys_tables, innodb_sys_tablespace* in information schema).

So whenever the server starts up, InnoDB tries to load all the table present in sys_tables, sys_tablespaces.  So it tries to open `foo`.`bar` table but the state is DISCARD. So that warning is issued.

## **How to remove the table/warning:**

1. Create a fake `bar.frm` & `bar.ibd` inside the `foo` folder of data
   directory.
2. Start the server and give the drop table `foo`.`bar`. It
   should remove the table from the dictionary and removes the warning too.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I copied a .frm from another table and created a 0 byte bar.ibd file, but I still got the error message when I started the server and couldn't do a drop table afterwards.

Comment: you can create the fake bar.frm file directly and it should be inside the database directory. Can you paste the log while starting the server?